# IoC: advantages of using a child container in web based app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

I'm interested in knowing if there are any advantages to creating a child container for each request in a web based application?

The tech stack I'm using includes StructureMap & ASP.NET MVC, which is not particularly relevant but included as background info.

Answer (score 0):

Without a child container, the application container would otherwise be responsible for holding *all* instances created during the application's lifetime.

That is an enormous memory leak.

Comment: Surely this an assumption of how the container is implemented and it disposes of instances?

Comment: @AWC: I am making the assumption that containers, in general, track the instances they create. That is a solid assumption for any implementation of an IoC container, otherwise "container" wouldn't be a very fitting name. I make no assumptions about disposal: I simply mean that if a container goes out of scope, its objects go with it.